# How do I pass non-printable characters to BCP's field/row terminator parameters?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, bcp, flat-file, csv

I have a tab delimited file I am trying to import into SQL Server 2012; the row terminator is CRLF.  The following is my BCP statement in PowerShell:

```
bcp database.dbo.table IN C:\filePath.tsv -SserverName -UuserName -Ppassword -c -t\t -r\n
```

Which reports a

> Unexpected EOF encountered

error.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is not working.  An extra eye would be great.

**EDIT:**
After review, I think the problem is with -r\n...What is the metacharacter for CRLF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode it in hex:

```
bcp database.dbo.table IN C:\filePath.tsv -SserverName -UuserName -Ppassword -c -t0x9 -r0xa
```

You can use multiple characters by encoding each in hex and appending them together. For example, we use the record separator character, carriage return, and newline to separate each row, so we pass `0x1e0d0a` as the value of the `-r` parameter.

I use [ASCII Table](http://asciitable.com) to do quick lookups for this.

Comment: Wow! That works alot faster now than before.  Will definitely reference ASCII from now on.  I don't know if this is off topic, but, how do I handle rogue tabs (some columns have 1,2,3 tabs between them)?

Comment: @JeffOrris You can't. You should choose a different field terminator. We use the unit separator character `0x1f`. We've never encountered any data that contains that character.

Comment: So I decided to script my tabs to unit separators. Made my imports 10x faster...Im BCPing 10,000 records/sec just about.